# Getting error after clicking 'calculate' button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am learning express node.js and trying to run simple calculator code but anytime i press on the button i don't get any response back and also i don't get any errors in my code so i am kind of lost of what i am doin wrong. here is the sample of it so hoping someone can pinpoint me where i am goin wrong will include html code and calculator.js and the error which i am getting. Thank you in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="n1" placeholder="Enter Number1" value="">
      <input type="text" name="n2" placeholder="Enter Number2" value="">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +"/index.html");
});

app.post("/",function(res,req){
  var n1 = Number(req.body.n1);
  var n2= Number(req.body.n2);
  var result= n1 + n2;
  res.send("The result of calculation is" + result);
});

app.listen(2424,function(){
  console.log("Server started on 2424");
});
```

But here is the error i am getting as soon as i am clicking calculate button:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'n1')
    at C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\calc.js:12:28
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at C:\Users\Taniya\desktop\calculator\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:137:5
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
```

Comment: `app.post("/",function(res,req){` you inverted `res` and `req`, try `app.post("/",function(req,res){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post("/",function(res,req){
```

You should change this to

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){
```

**This worked for me!**

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing req.body, when you're doing request? Looks like that is undefined!

Comment: I inverted app.post("/",function(res,req){      to app.post("/",function(req,res){ and now it's working